# Display thunderbird unread count docky gnome

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, docky

I was wondering if it's possible to display the unread e-mail's count on the Thunderbird icon on my Docky bar. I am using ubuntu gnome and already have tried multiple things which include:

- Installing Docky Unread Count 0.7.0 Add-on for Thunderbid
- Gnome Shell integration Plug-In.

but nothing seems to work.

If it's not possible is there any way I can get a notification using just thunderbird in the top bar of gnome shell? I don't want to use evolution.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Docky version: 2.2.1.1, Docky Unread Count 0.7.2, Thunderbird 38.5.1. Screenshot:  http://i.imgur.com/vozO4AM.png